# Как получить информацию о пользователе VK (имя, например) по его id с помощью vk_api?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Есть такой код

```
import vk_api
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType
from main_token import main_token

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token = main_token)
session_api = vk_session.get_api()
longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk_session)

for event in longpoll.listen():
        if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
                if event.to_me:
                        msg = event.text.lower()
                        id = event.user_id
                        info = session_api.users.get(users_id = event.user_id)
                        print(len(info))
                        vk_session.method("messages.send", {"user_id":id, "message":f"Hi, @id{event.user_id}","random_id":0})

Да, я знаю, что этот вопрос уже задавался, но у меня все равно ничего не работает. Почему-то структура info имеет в итоге размер 0, то есть никакой информации я не получаю. Как это исправить?
```

Comment: Как минимум потому что у метода `users.get` не существует никакого аргумента `users_id`, читайте документацию

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
id = event.user_id
user_get = vk.users.get(user_ids=(id))
user_get = user_get[0]
```

Вдруг, если нужно:

```
first_name = user_get['first_name'] #Имя пользователя
last_name = user_get['last_name'] #Фамилия
```